# saving to localstorage onkeyup

Tags: javascript

I am trying to save form data to localstorage on keyup event with javascript. I have the following code but I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onkeyup' of null".

**html**

```
<input type="text" id="username" />
```

**javascript**

```
var user = document.getElementById("username");
user.onkeyup = function(){
    localStorage.setItem('user', user.value);
};
```

Comment: Is your document loaded when you execute the JS code ? If it's not, then your var user is null when your JS code is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access DOM element before loaded is completed. wrap your code inside a function and call in window.onload

```
function init() {
var user = document.getElementById("username");
user.onkeyup = function(){
    localStorage.setItem('user', user.value);
};
}
window.onload = init;
```